# XSLT Wrapping text with multiple tags

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have this span element with a class of `autbib-pc-bold-italic`

```
<span class="autbib-pc-bold-italic">autbib</span>
```

I want to create element tags base on the @class attribute value:

**My output should be:**

```
<autbib><pc><bold><italic>autbib</italic></bold></pc></autbib>
```

Here is my xsl templates:

```
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@class,'autbib')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="pbib.loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(tokenize(@class, '-'))"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="class" select="tokenize(@class, '-')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="pbib.loop">
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="count" select="count(tokenize(@class, '-')) + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="class" select="tokenize(@class, '-')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$class[1]}">
       <xsl:if test="not($index = $count)">
            <xsl:element name="{$class[$index]}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:if test="not($index = $count)">
        <xsl:call-template name="pbib.loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And have this output which is wrong:

```
<autbib>
    <pc>autbib</pc>
    <bold>autbib</bold>
    <italic>autbib</italic>
</autbib>
```

**I need to have this output:**

```
<autbib>
    <pc>
        <bold>
            <italic>autbib</italic>
        </bold>
    </pc>
</autbib>
```

My problem is that I'm not sure where I should place `xsl:apply-template` so that tags wrap with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="span[contains(@class,'autbib')]">
  <xsl:param name="classes" select="tokenize(@class, '-')"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($classes[1])">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{$classes[1]}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="classes" select="$classes[position() gt 1]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With Saxon 9.4 that transforms the input

```
<span class="autbib-pc-bold-italic">autbib</span>
```

into the result

```
<autbib>
   <pc>
      <bold>
         <italic>autbib</italic>
      </bold>
   </pc>
</autbib>
```